# What does "but" mean here?

Tags: prepositions

> Which college one attends may influence opportunity at the entry level, but 10 years later, it makes no difference in terms of achievement and fulfillment.

I suspect "but 10 years later" in this sentence because I learned that *but* is used as preposition meaning "except" but I think this meaning is not suitable in this context. I think maybe *but* used as preposition has other meanings. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: _But_ can be used as a preposition. For example, _nothing but the truth_. But it is more commonly used as a coordinating conjunction, as it is in this case. Note also that it should not be _make_ but (conjunction) _makes_.

Comment: but, conjunction, used to introduce an added statement, usually something that is different from what you have said before [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but)

Comment: Omit the '10 years later' (or put it to the end of the second independent clause) to simplify analysis. "Doing A may cause X, but it (ie doing A) makes no difference [in the long run / 10 years later]."

Answer (score 1):

Used as a conjunction in this way, "but" draws a contrast between the first and second parts of the statement. Compare the following:

Which college you attend makes a big difference to your starting salary, and five years later the difference in pay can be $5000 per year.

Which college you attend makes a big difference to your starting salary, but five years later your pay will be the same.

In the first example, the first and second parts carry parallel meanings, so "and" is used as a conjunction to prepare the hearer/reader for this conclusion. In the second example, the two parts carry contrasting information, and "but" indicates this. In place of "but", you could use "though" or "however" with much the same meaning.

Comment: @lan You mean comma after later(but 10 years later,) should be omitted,right?

Comment: I'd say that second comma is acceptable but not necessary. Use of commas is a convention which has changed over time, and fewer are used at the present time than would have been included in the past.